# Why does this entropy change formula for heating water blow up at $T_{1}=0$?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

My textbook says:

Next we consider a more complicated problem: heating *m* grams of water, from $T_{1}$ to  $T_{2}$. The entropy change is $$S_{2}-S_{1}=\int mc_{w} \dfrac{T_{2}}{T_{1}}=mc_{w}\ln\dfrac{T_{2}}{T_{1}}$$
I would like to use this formula to calculate the entropy increase in water heated from $0^{\circ} C$ to $20^{\circ} C$ but the formula blows up for this case. Why can I not apply this formula?

Comment: It also blows up at $T_2=0$, because $\ln 0$ is undefined.

Comment: @user44816 -- you don't need to pick an answer in two minutes!

Comment: Unrelated, but your text has an _interesting_ opinion on what an integral is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use degrees Kelvin

Answer (score 3):

As DepHb pointed out, you need to use absolute temperature (say Kelvin).

An obvious check that you should do when thinking about any physics equation is whether it would still hold if you used different units.   In your case, it's obvious that you would get a different answer if you used Fahrenheit instead of Celius, so your interpretation of the equation must be wrong.   In this case, it's because the zero value for Celsius (and Fahrenheit) aren't a natural value -- they are just arbitrary.   Using a scale with absolute zero as the zero value fixes this.   Also, note that if you used [Rankine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine_scale) instead of Kelvin, it would give the same result, which is a good check.